# Container exited with a non-zero exit code 134

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, hadoop

I'm trying to run some matlab deployed code in Hadoop 2.7.3 with MCR from Matlab R2016a (9.0.1) in Ubuntu 16.04.

When trying to execute a Matlab example's deployed code, with the command:

```
sudo ./run_airlinesmall.sh /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901 -D mw.mcrroot=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901 "/pruebas/datasets/airline.csv" /pruebas/resultados/myresults
```

I receive the following error output:

```
    Using MATLAB_HADOOP_INSTALL: /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop
    Using HADOOP_PREFIX: /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop
    Using HADOOP_HOME: /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop
    Find out Hadoop version: /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop version
    Use Hadoop V2 JAR files
    ------------------------------------------
    Launch Hadoop job airlinesmall.ctf
    hola
    /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901
    Executing: /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop jar "/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/toolbox/mlhadoop/jar/a2.2.0/mwmapreduce.jar" com.mathworks.hadoop.MWMapReduceDriver   "-D" "mw.mcrroot=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901" "airlinesmall.ctf" "/pruebas/datasets/airline.csv" "/pruebas/resultados/myresults"
    java.library.path: /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/lib/native
    HDFSCTFPath=hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/airlinesmall/airlinesmall.ctf
    Uploading CTF into distributed cache completed.
    mapred.child.env: MCR_CACHE_ROOT=/tmp,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64
    mapred.child.java.opts: -Xmx200m -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64
    New java.library.path: /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/lib/native:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64
    Using MATLAB mapper.
    Set input format class to: ChunkFileRecordReader.
    Using MATLAB reducer.
    Set outputformat class to: class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat
    Set map output key class to: class com.mathworks.hadoop.MxArrayWritable2
    Set map output value class to: class com.mathworks.hadoop.MxArrayWritable2
    Set reduce output key class to: class com.mathworks.hadoop.MxArrayWritable2
    Set reduce output value class to: class com.mathworks.hadoop.MxArrayWritable2
    *************** run ******************
    16/10/05 10:27:59 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
    16/10/05 10:28:00 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    16/10/05 10:28:00 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
    16/10/05 10:28:00 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1475655722794_0002
    16/10/05 10:28:00 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1475655722794_0002
    16/10/05 10:28:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://pcitbu:8088/proxy/application_1475655722794_0002/
    16/10/05 10:28:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1475655722794_0002
    16/10/05 10:28:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1475655722794_0002 running in uber mode : false
    16/10/05 10:28:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
    16/10/05 10:28:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1475655722794_0002_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    Exception from container-launch.
    Container id: container_1475655722794_0002_01_000002
    Exit code: 134
    Exception message: /bin/bash: línea 1:  6811 Abortado                (`core' generado) /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx200m -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-pcitbu/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1475655722794_0002/container_1475655722794_0002_01_000002/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475655722794_0002/container_1475655722794_0002_01_000002 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 127.0.1.1 35025 attempt_1475655722794_0002_m_000000_0 2 > /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475655722794_0002/container_1475655722794_0002_01_000002/stdout 2> /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475655722794_0002/container_1475655722794_0002_01_000002/stderr
...


Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=134: /bin/bash: línea 1:  6944 Abortado                (`core' generado) /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx200m -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-pcitbu/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1475655722794_0002/container_1475655722794_0002_01_000004/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475655722794_0002/container_1475655722794_0002_01_000004 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 127.0.1.1 35025 attempt_1475655722794_0002_m_000000_2 4 > /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475655722794_0002/container_1475655722794_0002_01_000004/stdout 2> /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475655722794_0002/container_1475655722794_0002_01_000004/stderr

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 134

16/10/05 10:28:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/10/05 10:28:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1475655722794_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1475655722794_0002_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

16/10/05 10:28:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 16
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=4
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=4
        Other local map tasks=3
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=8006
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=8006
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=0
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=8006
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=8198144
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
```

I've been trying for a while but I have not been able to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
LOGS:

/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475737682094_0001/container_1475737682094_0001_01_000001/stderr

```
oct 06, 2016 9:10:36 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFORMACIÓN: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
oct 06, 2016 9:10:36 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFORMACIÓN: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
oct 06, 2016 9:10:36 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFORMACIÓN: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class
oct 06, 2016 9:10:36 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFORMACIÓN: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
oct 06, 2016 9:10:36 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFORMACIÓN: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
oct 06, 2016 9:10:36 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFORMACIÓN: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
oct 06, 2016 9:10:36 AM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFORMACIÓN: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475737682094_0001/container_1475737682094_0001_01_000002/stderr (and same for containers 2, 3 and 5)

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<fl::i18n::MessageCatalog::MessageCatalogNotInitialized>'
  what():  Message Catalog has not been initialized by a successful call to MessageCatalog::MessageCatalogInit
```

nodemanager log:

```
2016-10-06 10:40:16,391 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=134: /bin/bash: línea 1:  9908 Abortado                (`core' generado) /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx200m -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-pcitbu/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 127.0.1.1 33516 attempt_1475742936553_0001_m_000000_1 3 > /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003/stdout 2> /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003/stderr
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: 
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Container exited with a non-zero exit code 134
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003 transitioned from RUNNING to EXITED_WITH_FAILURE
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,404 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-pcitbu/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,404 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=root OPERATION=Container Finished - Failed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=Container failed with state: EXITED_WITH_FAILURE    APPID=application_1475742936553_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,404 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003 transitioned from EXITED_WITH_FAILURE to DONE
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,404 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Removing container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003 from application application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,404 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,479 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1475742936553_0001_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,486 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Stopping container with container Id: container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003
    2016-10-06 10:40:16,487 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=root IP=127.0.0.1    OPERATION=Stop Container Request    TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1475742936553_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003
    2016-10-06 10:40:17,126 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Starting resource-monitoring for container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003
    2016-10-06 10:40:17,127 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Stopping resource-monitoring for container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003
    2016-10-06 10:40:17,169 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 9727 for container-id container_1475742936553_0001_01_000001: 397.7 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 2.8 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,410 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_1475742936553_0001_01_000003]
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,486 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1475742936553_0001_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,490 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Start request for container_1475742936553_0001_01_000004 by user root
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,490 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=root IP=127.0.0.1    OPERATION=Start Container Request   TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1475742936553_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1475742936553_0001_01_000004
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,490 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Adding container_1475742936553_0001_01_000004 to application application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,491 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000004 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZING
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,491 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_INIT for appId application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,491 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event APPLICATION_INIT for appId application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,491 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got APPLICATION_INIT for service mapreduce_shuffle
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,491 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler: Added token for job_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,491 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000004 transitioned from LOCALIZING to LOCALIZED
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,504 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000004 transitioned from LOCALIZED to RUNNING
    2016-10-06 10:40:18,505 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: 
...
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exit code: 134
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Exception message: /bin/bash: línea 1: 10040 Abortado                (`core' generado) /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx200m -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-pcitbu/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 127.0.1.1 33516 attempt_1475742936553_0001_m_000000_3 5 > /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005/stdout 2> /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005/stderr
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: 
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=134: /bin/bash: línea 1: 10040 Abortado                (`core' generado) /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx200m -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v901/bin/glnxa64 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-pcitbu/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 127.0.1.1 33516 attempt_1475742936553_0001_m_000000_3 5 > /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005/stdout 2> /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005/stderr
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: 
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,458 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerExecutor:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,459 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Container exited with a non-zero exit code 134
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,459 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005 transitioned from RUNNING to EXITED_WITH_FAILURE
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,459 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,468 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,497 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:8042
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,497 WARN org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: HttpServer Acceptor: isRunning is false. Rechecking.
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,497 WARN org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: HttpServer Acceptor: isRunning is false
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,498 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000001 is : 143
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,505 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-pcitbu/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,505 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000001 transitioned from RUNNING to EXITED_WITH_FAILURE
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,505 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=root OPERATION=Container Finished - Failed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=Container failed with state: EXITED_WITH_FAILURE    APPID=application_1475742936553_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,505 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005 transitioned from EXITED_WITH_FAILURE to DONE
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,505 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000001
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-pcitbu/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1475742936553_0001/container_1475742936553_0001_01_000001
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Removing container_1475742936553_0001_01_000005 from application application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,518 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=root OPERATION=Container Finished - Failed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=Container failed with state: EXITED_WITH_FAILURE    APPID=application_1475742936553_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1475742936553_0001_01_000001
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1475742936553_0001_01_000001 transitioned from EXITED_WITH_FAILURE to DONE
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Removing container_1475742936553_0001_01_000001 from application application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,597 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Applications still running : [application_1475742936553_0001]
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,598 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Waiting for Applications to be Finished
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,598 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1475742936553_0001 transitioned from RUNNING to APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,598 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-pcitbu/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,598 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event APPLICATION_STOP for appId application_1475742936553_0001
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,599 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1475742936553_0001 transitioned from APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP to FINISHED
    2016-10-06 10:40:25,599 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.loghandler.NonAggregatingLogHandler: Scheduling Log Deletion for application: application_1475742936553_0001, with delay of 10800 seconds
```

complete log: http://pastebin.com/j76TjcHF

Now sometimes it prints that message, othertimes the system just reboot.
Tell me if you may need more info.

Comment: Can you update your post with logs

Comment: Exit code 134 means your MatLab job aborted for some reason like libraries not found etc. Look at the nodemanager logs and try running manually your task. You can find paths etc in job.xml

Comment: nodemanager log added. System reboots sometimes when executing the tasks